# Is the Lebesgue measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra the only measure which is equal to the volume of a closed rectangle on each closed rectangle?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $R_d$ be a d-dimensional closed rectangle. I want to show that each measure $\mu$ defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for which
\begin{equation}
\mu(R_d)=l(R_d) \qquad  \forall R_d
\end{equation}
is equal to the restriction of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{B}^d$: $\mu\equiv m$. Where $l(R_d)$ is the volume of the rectangle.
I know that an outer measure $\mu:\mathcal{B}^d\to[0,\infty]$ has the following properties:

1. $\mu \cdot(\emptyset)=0$
2. $A\subset B \Rightarrow \mu \cdot (A)\leq\mu\cdot (B)$
3. $A_n\subset\mathcal{B}^d, n\in\mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \mu(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n})\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$

In addition, every closed rectangle is $m$-measurable, thus
\begin{equation}
m(Z)=m(Z \cap R_d)+m(Z\cap R_d^C),
\end{equation}
and that $m(R_d)=l(R_d)$.

I am very lost on how to proceed and would be very grateful for any help. Thank you!

Comment: One possibility is to use the [Caratheodory extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem). Alternatively, you can show that $\mu$ and $m$ agree on open sets and sets of (Lebesgue) measure zero, then use approximation of Borel sets by $G_\delta$ sets. Or something like that...